# Some Angular material modules are not working in angular 10

Tags: angular-material

app.module.ts

Here *MatToolbarModule* is not working.
The error is

```
File 'h:/Chale/Angular Projects/CertiStore/node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

*MatListModule* is not working.
The error is

```
Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/material/list"' has no exported member 'MatListModule'.ts(2305)
```

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StudentDashboardComponent,
    UploadComponent,
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I get rid of these errors???
Is it because of the newest version in angular or is their anything I missed?

Comment: You need to replace import-directives, for example

import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material';

Comment: @FaizaanKhan I did that but it still the same.